# How much data can be reliably passed between processes?

Tags: linux, stdout, stdin

I have a server written in nodejs which is calling a Rust binary using the spawn functionality and I need to pass a few megabytes worth of data between the binary and the nodejs server. Would it be reliable to do so using stdin and stdout or should I rather write the data to a file? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to user stdin/out, and it would be also quite realiable. but espcially for stuff that is in the MB realm I'd recommend to write the file to disk and read it from the other process. Especially because that is probably going to happen anyway as large data like this is not just handed over from one process to the next, but written to a buffer in ram. you can do the same by writing your data to a ramdisk path like /tmp and and just read it from there. you will little performance loss that way and can relieve the os of having to deal with floating page buffers.

in the end it does not really matter. yes it should be as reliable as writing it to a ramdisk. pro for wirting it to actual hard disk/ssd: if your second process dies prematurely the intermitten results are not lost.

Comment: Can you name any popular distro where /tmp is a ramdisk by default?

Comment: That's what I though. Thank you for the confirmation.

Comment: @JanBeneš This confirmation is questionable. There's nothing wrong with pushing GBs of data through pipes. It's reliable, fast and happens all the time in the Linux world. A few MBs is a no-brainer. Saving intermediate data into `/tmp`, will typically not be as fast because it's a regular directory on disk. It's a plus in case of a crash, but whether you need that is up to you. Using a proper ramdisk like ramfs would address the speed issue, but it's still slower since the pipeline isn't running all at once and there are no direct reliability benefits. This answer is based on FUD.